# Extracting text from a textfile starting with one word and ending on a different line with a different word

Tags: vb.net

I need to extract text from a text file starting with the order number(eg. Order1) and ending with an empty line with all other lines between the order number and the empty line extracted as well for a query. Really have no idea how to go about this so any help is greatly appreciated!

so the file name is "CustomerDetails.txt" and I'd imagine the code would look something like this

```
    If IO.File.Exists("CustomerDetails.txt") Then
        Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(“CustomerDetails.txt")
    End If
```

and then taking for example "order1" in that text file until the blank space and displaying that is a list box

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the input file? And a sample of the output you expect? And as much code as you can write that gets us from a file to the desired output? Then you can say, "I don't know how to write the line **blah blah blah**". Then we can help.

Comment: so the file name is "CustomerDetails.txt" and I'd imagine the code would look something like this   ```If IO.File.Exists("CustomerDetails.txt") Then Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(“CustomerDetails.txt")``` and then taking for example "order1" in that text file until the blank space and displaying that is a list box

Comment: Please edit your question and include the actual text of the file. Then show us the expected output and your code - in your question.

Answer (score 0):

"Really have no idea how to go about this "
The thinking could go like this...
A text file has a string in it.
I could look up the `String` class in .net and see if there are any methods that could help me.
Search for "String class in .net"
Looks like we can use a combination of `String.IndexOf(String, Int32)` and String.Substring(Int32, Int32)

Find the IndexOf your order. The string will be the order "Order1" and we will start looking at index 0 so the Int32 will be 0. Then find the end index. Start looking at the index we just found and stop at the first blank line. We can get the length required by the `.Substring method by subtracting the start index from the end index. Now we can extract the text of Order 1 with the substring method.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OrderText As String = "Order 1" 'this could be set with TextBox1.Text
    'Get the string out of the file
    Dim s As String = File.ReadAllText("CustomerDetails.txt")
    'Find the index of the order, this overload assumes start index is 0
    Dim startIndex As Integer = s.IndexOf(OrderText) 'starts lookint at beginning
    'Find the index of the first blank line after the startIndex 
    '2 new lines make a bland line
    Dim endIndex As Integer = s.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine, startIndex)
    'Return the string that stars at startIndex with a length of end minus start
    Dim Order As String = s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)
    'I am going to guess that the details of the order are on separate lines
    Dim lines() As String = Order.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    For Each line As String In lines
        ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
    Next
End Sub
```